# Problems with wordpress url

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

Initial wordpress url - **localhost/wordpress/**

In my wordpress navigation bar, i have a custom page called "Groups". On clicking "Groups",  the url changes to 
**localhost/wordpress/groups/**

and the page shows me all the groups created..

Now i want to click on this(say group name is 'students' ) group to show me more details of the group and the link should be like this :-
**localhost/wordpress/groups/students/**

How to work on the last part ?

I have notice the practical example of this in buddypress "Groups" page

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT create CPT for groups in BuddyPress (relates to the other answer).

Groups directory has the slug `/groups/`, as you already found out.
To create an URL `/groups/students/` you need just to create an ordinary group in your BuddyPress installation with its name `Students`. You can do that on `/groups/create/` page. This group will have the required `students` slug.

Related information:
General info about groups: https://codex.buddypress.org/administrator-guide/groups/
Group types (that's like categories for groups): https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/group-types/

Answer (score -1):

You should create a custom post type (*students*) and also register a custom taxonomy (*groups*) to the newly created post type, then create a taxonomy term *student* with which you will associate your new *students* posts.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types
https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies

I'd recommend either register them in your theme or create your own plugin to register these if you know how to code. If not, you can search for plugins that let you create custom post types and taxonomies.